# Upload file bigger than 12k with Python requests doesn't work on Ubuntu

Tags: python-2.7, http, ubuntu, python-requests

I need to upload a file and json string in one POST. I do it with the following code:

```
    url = 'https://service.mydomain.com'
    self.session = requests.Session()
    self.session.mount(url, HTTPAdapter(max_retries=5))

    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        form = MultipartEncoder({
            "request": json_request,
            "file": f,
        })

        headers = {'Authorization': api_key,
                   "Content-Type": form.content_type}

        try:
            resp = self.session.post(UPLOAD_URL,
                                     headers=headers,
                                     data=form,
                                     verify=True,
                                     cookies=cookies)
```

It works just fine on my MacOS machine, but on Ubuntu same code can't upload files bigger than 12k, while smaller files uploaded with no issue

This is what I get for files bigger than 12k on Ubuntu:

```
400 Client Error: Bad Request for url
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Upgrade of requests-toolbelt from 0.4.0 to 0.8.0 solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade of requests-toolbelt from 0.4.0 to 0.8.0 solved the issue